# AWS Servicediscovery in a VPC with ECS without a LB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

With the CDK I implemented:

- a VPC

```
         self.vpc = ec2.Vpc(
            self, 
            "rcs-vpc",
            vpc_name="rcs-vpc",
            max_azs=2,
            ip_addresses=ec2.IpAddresses.cidr("10.180.0.0/16"),
            # configuration will create 2 groups in 2 AZs = 4 subnets.
            subnet_configuration=[
                ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                    subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                    name="public",
                    cidr_mask=24
                ),
                ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                    subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
                    name="private",
                    cidr_mask=24
                )
            ],
            nat_gateway_provider=ec2.NatProvider.gateway(),
            nat_gateways=1
        )
```

- The privateDNSNamespace in it

```
        self.rcs_sd_namespace = servicediscovery.PrivateDnsNamespace(
            self, 
            "rcs-sd-private-namespace",
            name="rcs.internal",
            vpc=vpc_stack.vpc
        )
```

- an ECS instance (non-Fargate)
- with a ECS Cluster in that VPC

```
        self.ecs_cluster = ecs.Cluster(
            self,
            "rcs-ecs-cluster",
            cluster_name="rcs-cluster",
            vpc=vpc_stack.vpc
        )
```

- an EC2 container-service on that ECS Cluster

```
from aws_cdk import CfnOutput, Stack, Duration, Lazy
import aws_cdk.aws_ec2 as ec2
import aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 as elbv2
import aws_cdk.aws_ecs as ecs
import aws_cdk.aws_ecr as ecr
import aws_cdk.aws_ssm as ssm
import aws_cdk.aws_servicediscovery as servicediscovery
from constructs import Construct


class DSERootStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
        self.rcs_sd_namespace = servicediscovery.PrivateDnsNamespace.from_private_dns_namespace_attributes(
            self,
            "rcs-sd-namespace",
            namespace_arn=ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, parameter_name="rcs-sd-namespace-arn"),
            namespace_id=ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, parameter_name="rcs-sd-namespace-id"),
            namespace_name=ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, parameter_name="rcs-sd-namespace-name")
        )
        self.rcs_loadbalancer = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer.from_lookup(
            self,
            "rcs-loadbalancer",
            load_balancer_arn=ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, parameter_name="rcs-loadbalancer-arn")
        )
        self.dse_vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(
            self,
            "dse_vpc",
            vpc_id=ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, parameter_name="rcs-vpc-id")
        )
        self.dse_security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(
            self,
            "dse-security-group",
            security_group_name="dse-security-group",
            vpc=self.dse_vpc,
            description="Allow access to DSE",
            allow_all_outbound=True,
            disable_inline_rules=False
        )
        self.dse_security_group.add_ingress_rule(
            peer=ec2.Peer.any_ipv4(),
            connection=ec2.Port.all_traffic()
        )
        self.dse_security_group.add_egress_rule(
            peer=ec2.Peer.any_ipv4(),
            connection=ec2.Port.all_traffic()
        )
        self.dse_task_definition = ecs.TaskDefinition(
            self,
            "dse-task-definition",
            compatibility=ecs.Compatibility.EC2,
            network_mode=ecs.NetworkMode.AWS_VPC
        )
        self.dse_container = self.dse_task_definition.add_container(
            "dse-container",
            image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_ecr_repository(
                ecr.Repository.from_repository_name(
                    self,
                    "enter",
                    repository_name="test"
                )
            ),
            memory_limit_mib=512,
            port_mappings=[
                ecs.PortMapping(
                    name="http_port_mapping",
                    container_port=8000
                )
            ],
            logging=ecs.AwsLogDriver.aws_logs(
                mode=ecs.AwsLogDriverMode.NON_BLOCKING,
                stream_prefix="TEST"
            )
        )
        self.dse_service = ecs.Ec2Service(
            self,
            "dse-service",
            service_name="dse-service",
            assign_public_ip=False,
            cluster=ecs.Cluster.from_cluster_attributes(
                self,
                "dse-cluster",
                cluster_name=ssm.StringParameter.from_string_parameter_name(self, "rcs-cluster-name", string_parameter_name="rcs-cluster-name").string_value,
                vpc=self.dse_vpc
            ),
            cloud_map_options=ecs.CloudMapOptions(
                cloud_map_namespace=self.rcs_sd_namespace,
                name="dse",
                container=self.dse_container,
                container_port=8000,
                dns_record_type=servicediscovery.DnsRecordType.A,
                dns_ttl=Duration.seconds(10)
            ),
            security_groups=[
                self.dse_security_group
            ],
            task_definition=self.dse_task_definition
        )
```

- a cloud_map_option for that service with an A record and a PrivateDNSNamespace (which is associated with the VPC)

-> The ECS agent API gives me the same IP for the Container as CloudMap.
-> docker inspect

```
"Config": {
            "Hostname": "ip-10-180-3-249.REDACTEDREGION.compute.internal",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "dse",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8000/tcp": {}
            },
```

-> wget from another container:

```
~ $ wget dse.rcs.internal:8000
Connecting to dse.rcs.internal:8000 (10.180.3.249:8000)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.180.3.249): Connection refused
```

Now what I need is the container-service to communicate with:

- other instances in that VPC
- other container-services in that VPC
- lambda functions

Is there a possibility to use the VPC internal DNS via ServiceDiscovery without utilizing a Loadbalancer?
I tried to communicate from a BastionHost to the CloudMapService but its not possible to even ping the service.

Comment: Don't use `ping` to test connectivity, it uses ICMP protocol which is going to be blocked by default by all your VPC security groups. You should absolutely be able to establish communication between your different services running inside the VPC without adding a load balancer. You just need to open up the security groups accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I will see, what I can find out :D Then, is it also possible to configure a DNS and find the addresses of other services automatically? I thought this works via the awsvpc network but i cant find out how...

Comment: i think my question is actually: How do I connect the awsvpc with a servicediscovery, so that i can access a container via its servicediscovery dns name

Comment: "How do I connect the awsvpc with a servicediscovery, so that i can access a container via its servicediscovery dns name" You already did that with this step: "a cloud_map_option for that service with an A record and a PrivateDNSNamespace (which is associated with the VPC)" If that isn't working, then you will need to debug the dns resolution on your end, and if the DNS resolution is working then you need to work on your security group rules.

Comment: The DNS resolution works fine, which is great. But even though the security groups have  an ingress rule with any_ipv4() and port.all_traffic() I get a connection refused, if I want to call one container from the other - Trying with curl.

Comment: Does the DNS resolve to an internal IP VPC address? You're going to have to provide the actual details of your configuration and your debugging steps before anyone can help you further.

Comment: I added my configurations. What I get is a connection refused, if I try to call the container API from another container per wget but with the correct IP of the container.

Comment: I would look at your VPC flow logs next: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-flow-logs.html and possibly try using the AWS Reachability Analyzer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html to debug this further.

Comment: The logs are empty despite their starting config: "INFO: Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)". Reachability Analyzer tells me, that the ENIs of both services can reach each other through port on port 8000. But there are also no VPC Endpoint Services - is that a problem maybe? Or do they need a SRV record + the A record?

Comment: The IPs of the container are all listed in the EC2 instances private IPv4 addresses

Comment: They don't need an SRV record in addition to an A record. You only need 1 or the other, not both.

Comment: Do I have to expose the port of a container some other way than through the ways I did?  Maybe open the port on the EC2 Instance? I used EXPOSE in my Dockerfile and container_port in the cloud map. I can wget localhost on the container and i get a 200 but not from anywhere else

Comment: or do I need to add both my ECS container (services) to the same Cloud Map service? It seems a cloud map service has multiple tasks, is that my error in thinking? I thought they could connect, if the namespace is the same

Comment: You exposed the port via the `port_mappings` configuration in the task definition. But you also need to make sure the service that runs inside the docker image actually listens on that port. Just adding `EXPOSE` in your Dockerfile doesn't guarantee that. You actually have to configure the software running in the docker container to listen on that port.

Comment: Yeah, I checked. python uvicorn actually runs on port 8000 -> i checked locally on the container with wget that it does.

Comment: The security group of the ecs instance should matter concering the ENI of the containers correct? Since the ECS instance security group only accepts traffic from a loadbalancer.

Comment: The security group of the ECS instance should **not** matter, since you are using `awsvpc` network mode. Each ECS task gets its own ENI, which should have its own security group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254936/discussion-between-zu-jiry-and-mark-b).

Comment: The problem was the Container btw... it did not run itself. Always check your containers first.